# Different Hermitian metrics on a complex vector bundle define isomorphic unitary frame bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, hermitian-matrices

I wonder if it is true that different Hermitian metrics on a complex vector bundle define isomorphic unitary frame bundles, i.e., that this bundle is independent of the metric chosen to construct it. I've tried to prove it, without success.

I was also wondering if a Hermitian metric always exists on an arbitrary complex vector bundle.

Comment: Hermitian metrics always exist under weak assumptions on the base: Choose a locally finite cover over which the bundle is trivial (this is possible for a paracompact base) . Then choose any Hermitian metric $h_i$ on the trivializations $U_i \times \mathbb C^n$. Then use a partition of unity $\{p_i\}$, subordinate to the trivializing cover, to get a global Hermitian metric $h = \sum p_i h_i$.

Comment: @red_trumpet Thank you! Do you have any idea about the main question?

Comment: @juan1243 For the main question you can try to answer to this one: given two hermitian products $h_1,h_2$ on a complex vector space $V$ does there exist an invertible matrix which sends a $h_1$-ortonormal basis to a $h_2$-ortonormal basis?

Comment: @John117 Right, thank you!